# pandoc.table | table split in two part

Tags: r, pandoc

I tried multiple way like passing style as gird, multitable and split cells but in each case, my table split in two part, can someone please help

```
library(pander)   
l <- data.frame(id = 1, text = "Shake a tail feather!                               
     <ed><U+00A0><U+00BD><ed><U+00B2><U+0083><ed><U+00A0><U+00BC><ed><U+00BF><U+00BC> 
                              #whiteeeee #rrrrrrrrrr #eeeeeeeeeeeeee @                           
                                   Doubletree by fadfadsfasdf                               
                                        Evansville                                    
                                 https://fadfaffadsfafadsfadsfasdfads")
    pandoc.table(l, split.cells = c(10,100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `split.tables` parameter such as this:

`pandoc.table(l, split.cells = c(10,100), split.tables = Inf)`